# fedora 19 dependency issue

Tags: fedora, yum

I am getting this error while updating:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-4.fc19 will be updated
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-29.fc19 will be an update
---> Package openssl-devel.i686 1:1.0.1e-4.fc19 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-devel(x86-32) = 1:1.0.1e-4.fc19 for package: 1:openssl-static-1.0.1e-4.fc19.i686
---> Package openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-4.fc19 will be updated
---> Package openssl-devel.i686 1:1.0.1e-29.fc19 will be an update
---> Package openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-29.fc19 will be an update
---> Package openssl-libs.i686 1:1.0.1e-4.fc19 will be updated
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-4.fc19 will be updated
---> Package openssl-libs.i686 1:1.0.1e-29.fc19 will be an update
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-29.fc19 will be an update
---> Package openssl-static.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-4.fc19 will be updated
---> Package openssl-static.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-29.fc19 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:openssl-static-1.0.1e-4.fc19.i686 (@fedora)
           Requires: openssl-devel(x86-32) = 1:1.0.1e-4.fc19
           Removing: 1:openssl-devel-1.0.1e-4.fc19.i686 (@fedora)
               openssl-devel(x86-32) = 1:1.0.1e-4.fc19
           Updated By: 1:openssl-devel-1.0.1e-29.fc19.i686 (updates)
               openssl-devel(x86-32) = 1:1.0.1e-29.fc19
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have tried yum's suggestions, but still it's of no use

Comment: It looks like openssl-static-1.0.1e-4.fc19.i686 is the culprit. Could be that openssl-static-1.0.1e-29.fc19.i686 (the update) was not available as you tried to update. For this you could just try updating again. Or somthing else holds back the update of that file. You could try deinstalling openssl-static-1.0.1e-4.fc19.i686 - probably nothing needs it (it's only needed to link static binaries).